# A simple HTML page with content, but get blank page in Chrome 6.0.472.53

Tags: google-chrome

I am developing a ASP.Net web site and my page works normally in IE/Firefox/Opera

This is the page source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head><title> 
 Content Navigation
</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
dd222222222222222222222
    <div id="content-tree"> 
    </div> 



</body> 
</html>
```

It is simple, isn't it? But in my Chrome  6.0.472.53, I always get a blank page, just a blank page, nothing else.

After click the "Inspect Element" in context menu, here is the HTML DOM structure I see

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>
 Content Navigation
</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script></head></html>
```

Hmmm, the body is gone!
If I remove the jquery js reference line, body comes back

Is this a bug in Chrome or mine? my web host is IIS7.1

Thank you for any help

**Update:**

I have reported this issue to  [Chrome Help](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=23eda1ccb11d9173&hl=en)
And here is the screenshot:

Correct: http://img128.picfoco.com/img.php?id=1274578614&q=&jump=5176678858&ru=

Incorrect: http://img122.picfoco.com/img.php?id=778329008&q=&jump=4680429165&ru=

Comment: Renders properly from a regular file on Chrome 7.0.503.1 dev for Linux and 6.0.472.53 for Linux on two different machines, running Lucid and Maverick, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the reason now

because there is a "Connection:Close" in the response HTTP HEAD, and it only affects Chrome

After remove this head, everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure, I can't replicate the issue in my Chrome build. Can you try replacing your jQuery ref to the following from the Google repository? If it does the same, possibly try degrading to 1.3 and see if that produces the same results.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Test with this CDN link, same result  
If I added this line, white page;
If I remove this line, content is shown up;